# installing PHP_Unit test_helpers

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, pear, helper

I'm encountering this error while trying to install the **test_helpers**
from [here](http://pear.phpunit.de/).

```
**WARNING**: php_bin C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe appears to have a suffix \.\php.exe, but
 config variable php_suffix does not match

**ERROR**: The DSP test_helpers.dsp does not exist.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your php_bin setting by showing it with

```
$ pear config-get php_bin
```

Then fix it (by removing the `.\`) with

```
$ pear config-set php_bin the-new-val
```

Comment: Sorry, that removed the Warning  but the error is still the same :/

Comment: It's hard to compile php extensions on windows. Better use linux for this tasks. Sorry, this is the only sensible answer to this topic.